# trailing "=" being trimmed in angular2 url

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have a problem in an angular2 project where I'm generating a URL to be sent to a user via email. The URL in the email needs to contain a special ID which is passed in the router as:

{ path: somepath/:id }

The user then clicks on the url which will be:

http://localhost/somepath/{id}

My problem is that the id can contain a trailing "=" character which gets automatically trimmed off when navigating to the url (and therefore making the ID now incorrect)

I have tried encoding the id before adding it to the url making the url:

http://localhost/somepath/XXX%3D

but the encoded "=" (%3D) still gets trimmed off.

Is there any reason why encoded url values are still being trimmed off and is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Have you looked into any other options? Usually when you need to pass some token in the URL it's better to use queryParams and pass it like `http://localhost/somepath?id=...`

Comment: it should not fail, check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yXzWSbVggF4QtFRREk0B?p=preview), can you update this to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok was just a massive oversight on my part....

I the actual id was being masked by a random encryption generator that includes symbols and usually ends in "=". What I didn't notice however, was that there was a ")" that was being included in a couple of cases as well, which does not get encoded and was causing everything after it to be trimmed off when loading the URL.

Ended up fixing it by replacing the ")" with a different symbol that doesn't get encoded but one that doesn't have another function in Angular2 (in this case a "*").